# Network 3 Ubuntu machines for local data (not internet access)

Tags: networking, ethernet, nfs, openssh

I have anywhere from 3 to five machines all running ubuntu or ubuntustudio in my home office. They all have a good wifi connection but I need to access files from time to time (apart from wifi) such as setting up a render farm or using a Gimp or Blender file on one computer that is stored in another. I'm not usually copying a file but editing and rendering from it's original location.

I have an 8 port switch and would like to use it to network the machines while not effecting the wifi, if this is possible. All the issues I have read concern sharing internet or using openssh to copy a file over, which is not what I am after. I've used openssh but it gets slow over wireless which is why I would like to have a wired connection for this purpose.

I'm more of a graphics guy with some networking experience but I can get lost if too much is thrown at me. Any help (configuring switch/networkmanager,NFS etc.) in how to keep the wifi connection primary while using ethernet for local networking would be appreciated.

Comment: Either get a NAS (or use one of the machines as the server with NFS or Samba), or use something like Dropbox to have stuff sync'd automatically. If you need to share files only every now and then and/or the files are really big, consider using SSH to manually copy files.

Comment: If your question really was about how to copy large files fast, the roll out some wire to hook the machines up to each other using the switch. You will off-load traffic from your access point and gain speed. Reserve one port on the switch to connect to your access point (so you will have DHCP service). Please edit your question to make that more clear.

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan, edited. I have Samba but I've never found a tut to help me get it working the way I want. I've been looking into a NAS but won't be able to get one yet.

Comment: There's no need to have both WiFi and UTP. You'll see that once you have wired your connections that your internet traffic goes through the UTP (@ 1 Gigabit/sec) cable as well. It's just that you won't have two machines clogging up the airwaves while exchanging large files. It IS important that you have one cable between the switch and your access point or it won't work at all. Good luck!